# Help identify this Caribbean plant

Tags: species-identification, botany

Could you please help me identify this plant. I think it grew from some seeds we brought from Cuba (I might be mistaken though).

The plant in the picture is about 1.5 years old; it stands about 50 cm/20 in. tall. The leaf shown seems pretty large compared to the plant height, it's about 20 cm/8 in. long.

Leafs though appear shiny are rough to the touch on both sides, like very fine sandpaper.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The leafs remind me be a bit to a cocoa tree, but I am no expert on identification.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Thanks for the comment, I agree there is some similarity, but my tree's leaves seem wider and have those little teeth, while cocoa leaves don't seem to have teeth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I can answer my own question. Having spent the summer outside in full sun, the tree has produced flowers that helped us identify it.

[image]

It appears to be [*Cordia sebestena*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordia_sebestena)